# Why is it wrong to substitute $u=1/t$ in $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(t\right)dt$ and get an integral from $0$ to $0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, fake-proofs

As the title says, suppose we have an integral: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(t\right)dt,$$
and we set $t=\frac{1}{u}$. Then, we get $$-\int_{0}^{0}f\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)\frac{1}{u^{2}}du=0.$$

Where did this go wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is $1/0\ne\pm\infty$, but rather $\lim_{x\to 0}1/x=\pm\infty$.

Comment: This is a good question. The issue is that $t=1/u$ is an invalid substitution at $0$. You need to split the domain into $\int_0^\infty,\,\int_{-\infty}^0$ first and substitute separately

Comment: @Eric, there is no need for a click-bait title. I have not removed any content. There is no paradox here; using subjective judgements in titles has long been discouraged.

Comment: @FShrike: the question lacks context. It would be nice to get some details on the source of the problem. Did the asker try the substitution for some specific function  $f$ as a part of exercise? Are they aware of the theorem for substitution in integrals? Further note that such questions related to u-substitution have been dealt with many times on this site.

Answer (score 5):

It does not work because $\frac{1}{t}$ is not defined at $0$. However, you can split the integral in two parts
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^0f(t)dt+\int_0^{+\infty}f(t)dt $$
and set $u=\frac{1}{t}$ in each integral ($\frac{1}{t}$ is $\mathscr{C}^1$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ !). You get
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{f(1/u)}{u^2}du+\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{f(1/u)}{u^2}du=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f(1/u)}{u^2}du $$